# How to set the background color on a gridview row

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, rowdatabound

I was trying fire a row data bind event to a grid view. When data is being bound to grid view, i would like to check a condidtion , if the condidtion is satisfied , then i need to apply some color to that entire row..Please check the below code i am using..

```
protected void GridView4_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{

  if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
   {

    Textbox txtBox1 = (GridView)(e.Row.FindControl("Name of text box"));

      if(Condidtion)
      {
          txtBox1.enabled=false;
          txtBox1.bgcolor=somecolor;
      } 

   }

}
```

Please help me on this..

Comment: Currently, i am able to change color of one cell i.e the text box . how to do for all the cells of that row.

Comment: JavaScript / C# ? You seem confused

Answer (score 4, accepted):

below will change the color of row

```
  if(Condidtion)
  {
      e.Row.BackColor =somecolor;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is specifically selecting one textBox. If you want to apply the condition to all the  elements in the row you need to iterate through the controls on the row rather than selecting one and run that condition on each.

It would probably be easier to do this in JavaScript because drawing on a grid and maintaining state between postbacks is more complex.

Answer (score 0):

you can set background color like this

rows[i].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.RoyalBlue;

or you can set your defined color like bellow

rows[i].BackColor = "#fff23";